# how to show listview itemclick image into the alertbox using android json?

Tags: android, json, listview

i am having `ListView` where items are coming from server with images, now the problem is that if i click any item from `ListView` the alertbox will open and in that alertbox that particular image should also be there for example if i click cheese pizza so it will open an alert dialog box and it will show the same image in that box which is in `ListView`.

here is my submenu activity:

```
public class SubMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String RANK = "id";
    static String COUNTRY = "name";

    static String FLAG = "image";
    Integer i = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_menu);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        String SelectedId = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        // Get the view from listview_main.xml

        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        // @Override
        //  protected void onPreExecute() {
        //  super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        //   mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SubMenu.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        //   mProgressDialog.setTitle("Categories of Main categories.....");
        // Set progressdialog message
        //  mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        //  mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        //  mProgressDialog.show();
        // }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonarray = JsonFunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://cloud......com/broccoli/menu_typeitem.php?id=" + getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
//                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("main_menu_items");


                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    // map.put("id", jsonobject.getString("id"));
                    map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));

                    map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(SubMenu.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            // Close the progressdialog
            // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long rowId) {


            final AlertDialog customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubMenu.this).create();
            final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup
                    , null);
            customDialog.setView(dialogView);
            // set the custom customDialogimation components - text, image and button
            final TextView tvDistance = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.h2);

            //  crust.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
// public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {


            final Button ok = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ok);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    customDialog.dismiss();


                }
            });


            final Button cncl = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.canc);
            cncl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    customDialog.dismiss();


                }
            });


            Button _decrease = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.incr);
            Button _increase = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.decr);

            Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.crst);

            Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.adson);
            ArrayList<String> alspinner1 = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> alspinner2 = new ArrayList<>();


            final String[] _spvalue1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Crust_array);
            final String[] _spvalue2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.AddsOn_array);
            for (int i = 0; i < _spvalue1.length; i++) {
                alspinner1.add(_spvalue1[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < _spvalue2.length; i++) {
                alspinner2.add(_spvalue2[i]);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(dialogView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, alspinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(dialogView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, alspinner2);

            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

            final TextView _value = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.value);
            i = Integer.parseInt(_value.getText().toString());


            _decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String _stringVal;
                    Log.d("src", "Decreasing value...");
                    if (i > 0) {
                        i = i - 1;
                        _stringVal = String.valueOf(i);
                        _value.setText(_stringVal);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("src", "Value can't be less than 0");
                    }

                }
            });

            _increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String _stringVal;

                    Log.d("src", "Increasing value...");
                    i = i + 1;
                    _stringVal = String.valueOf(i);
                    _value.setText(_stringVal);
                }
            });
            customDialog.show();
        }


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

here on top the image should come,
thts a demo image
[image]
here is my listview adapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView id;
        TextView name;
        TextView population;
        ImageView image;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item1, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
       // id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idq);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.type1);


        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subimg);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
      //  id.setText(resultp.get(SubMenu.RANK));
        name.setText(resultp.get(SubMenu.COUNTRY));

        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(SubMenu.FLAG), image);
        // Capture ListView item click
        /**itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
        // Pass all data rank
        intent.putExtra("rank", resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK));
        // Pass all data country
        intent.putExtra("country", resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
        // Pass all data population
        intent.putExtra("population",resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
        // Pass all data flag
        intent.putExtra("flag", resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG));
        // Start SingleItemView Class
        context.startActivity(intent);

        }
        });*/
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

here is the actual image:
[image]

Comment: So alert is showing.. but you want to add image also?

Comment: yes my alert is workling ,now the same image which is in listview item, i want that on top of the alertbox..plz see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to show listview itemclick image into the alertbox using android
>   json?

`onItemClick` use `position` to get clicked row `HashMap` from   `arraylist`  :

```
HashMap<String, String> map =arraylist.get(position);
```

Get clicked row name and image URL from map and show it in `AlertDialog` as doing in `getView()` method of `ListViewAdapter`

Comment: @z.al:For which code is required ? you are already i think showing image in ListView from map. so do it in same way

Comment: i mean where to put this line to get the same image in alertbox

Comment: @z.al: use [Android Volley ImageLoader and NetworkImageView Example](http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-volley-imageloader-networkimageview-example/) to load image

Comment: @z.al: in `onItemClick` method add provided line. do you have added ImageView in AlertDialog?

Comment: do u have any idea abt it.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358294/how-to-add-edittext-input-data-into-sql-database-using-json-android/41358813?noredirect=1#comment69921598_41358813

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class SubMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

        JSONObject jsonobject;
        JSONArray jsonarray;
        ListView listview;
        ListViewAdapter adapter;
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
        static String RANK = "id";
        static String COUNTRY = "name";

        static String FLAG = "image";
        Integer i = 1;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_menu);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            String SelectedId = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");


            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


            // Get the view from listview_main.xml

            // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
            new DownloadJSON().execute();
        }

        // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

            // @Override
            //  protected void onPreExecute() {
            //  super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            //   mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SubMenu.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            //   mProgressDialog.setTitle("Categories of Main categories.....");
            // Set progressdialog message
            //  mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            //  mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            //  mProgressDialog.show();
            // }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Create an array
                arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                jsonarray = JsonFunctions
                        .getJSONfromURL("http://cloud.granddubai.com/broccoli/menu_typeitem.php?id=" + getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
    //                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("main_menu_items");


                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        // map.put("id", jsonobject.getString("id"));
                        map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));

                        map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        arraylist.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
                // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
                listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
                // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(SubMenu.this, arraylist);
                // Set the adapter to the ListView
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                // Close the progressdialog
                // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long rowId) {


                final AlertDialog customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubMenu.this).create();
                final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup
                        , null);
                customDialog.setView(dialogView);
                // set the custom customDialogimation components - text, image and button
                final TextView tvDistance = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.h2);
 ImageLoader imageLoader= new ImageLoader(dialogView.getContext());
                final ImageView desimage = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.desimage);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(arraylist.get(position).get("image"), desimage);
                //  crust.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    // public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {


                final Button ok = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ok);
                ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        customDialog.dismiss();


                    }
                });


                final Button cncl = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.canc);
                cncl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        customDialog.dismiss();


                    }
                });


                Button _decrease = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.incr);
                Button _increase = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.decr);
                Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.crust);
                Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.adson);
                ArrayList<String> alspinner1 = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> alspinner2 = new ArrayList<>();
                /**
                 * @purpose Array list to show the questions in spinner
                 */

                final String[] _spvalue1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Crust_array);
                final String[] _spvalue2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.AddsOn_array);
                for (int i = 0; i < _spvalue1.length; i++) {
                    alspinner1.add(_spvalue1[i]);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < _spvalue2.length; i++) {
                    alspinner2.add(_spvalue2[i]);
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(dialogView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, alspinner1);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, alspinner2);

                adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
                spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

                final TextView _value = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.value);
                i = Integer.parseInt(_value.getText().toString());


                _decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String _stringVal;
                        Log.d("src", "Decreasing value...");
                        if (i > 0) {
                            i = i - 1;
                            _stringVal = String.valueOf(i);
                            _value.setText(_stringVal);
                        } else {
                            Log.d("src", "Value can't be less than 0");
                        }

                    }
                });

                _increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String _stringVal;

                        Log.d("src", "Increasing value...");
                        i = i + 1;
                        _stringVal = String.valueOf(i);
                        _value.setText(_stringVal);
                    }
                });
                customDialog.show();
            }


        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    onBackPressed();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

It's the solution. Try this.

Comment: it shows variable imageLoader might not have been initialize..but u hav already initialize it

Comment: i will post the solution

Comment: hi sneha, can u tell me how to show the demo image look more bigger then what it shows..i will post the actual image

Comment: hey, if i try ur code for the same image ,my one spinner (addson looks white )and showing text also in white colour..how can it b possible

Comment: Compare the code of both the spinner. I think you will find the problem. @z.al

Comment: can we put the same name also the way we have put images from listview?

Comment: I didn't get you @z.al

Comment: like i have got image from the listview item from map (images) the same way name is also there ,,,i want that in my heading

Comment: Yes. Its possible.

Comment: i tried using same method the way u tried for images but m getting error

Comment: use heading.setText(arraylist.get(position).get("name"));

Comment: hi sneha do u know json parsing for adding data into sql..........plz see here.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358294/how-to-add-edittext-input-data-into-sql-database-using-json-android

Comment: hi, do u knw anything abt the question i post?

Comment: thts ok  , i gt d solution

Comment: do u knw this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41362239/how-can-i-send-radio-button-value-and-switch-case-option-to-server-using-json-an

Answer (score -1):

hi i gt the solution here:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long rowId) {

            final AlertDialog customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubMenu.this).create();
            final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup
                    , null);
            customDialog.setView(dialogView);
            HashMap<String, String> map =arraylist.get(position);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.desimage);
            ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(SubMenu.this);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(map.get(SubMenu.FLAG), image);

            //  crust.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
// public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {


            final Button ok = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ok);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    customDialog.dismiss();


                }
            });


            final Button cncl = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.canc);
            cncl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    customDialog.dismiss();


                }
            });
```

Comment: No need to post it @z.al as you see in my answer i am already saying `Get clicked row name and image URL from map and show it in AlertDialog as doing in getView() method of ListViewAdapter` . and code only answers are also not good.

Comment: yeah but the newcomers like need to have refer from the code only

Comment: Ok as you wish :)