# How to add edittext input data into sql database using json,android?

Tags: android, mysql, json, registration

i am working on registration form where i have to fill all the fields and the `EditText` input data should go to the database using json parser.but am facing a problem here ..when i try example  `fn.gettext().toString()`..it gives me red line that" Method `getText()` must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker ".now everything is fine only this line gives me error.i don't know whether this is the correct way to send data as i m newbie here.

here is my `Registration.java` class:

```
public class RegistrationForm extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText fn,ln,mb,em,pw,cpw,dob,gen;
    Switch sw;
    RadioGroup male,feml;
    Switch swth;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;



    private static String url_create_book = "http://cl...com/broccoli/creatinfo.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";




    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    Context c;
    int i=0;


    Button sub;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_form);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


         fn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fnm) ;
       ln=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lnm) ;
         mb=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile) ;
         em=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email) ;
        pw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass) ;
         cpw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cpass) ;
        RadioButton male=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rgm) ;

        RadioButton feml=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rgf) ;

        Switch swth=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.mySwitch) ;









        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sub2);

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                new CreateNewProduct().execute();



                // startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationForm.this, Home.class));


            }
        });


    }



    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegistrationForm.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating books..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }




        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String fname = fn.getText().toString();
            String lname = ln.getText().toString();
            String email = em.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("First_Name", fname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Last_Name",lname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));


            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_book,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

here is my php file for adding data :

```
<?php

/

// array for JSON response

include ('config.php');


// check for required fields

if (isset($_POST['First_Name']) && isset($_POST['Last_Name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $fname = $_POST['First_Name'];
    $lname = $_POST['Last_Name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];



    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO UserInfo(First_Name, Last_Name, email) VALUES('$fname', '$lname ', '$email')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

i am trying to add few fields if this will work..i will add full fields .

```
here is my logcat:

2-28 14:11:44.201 3245-3504/com.example.zeba.broccoli E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                         Process: com.example.zeba.broccoli, PID: 3245
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.example.zeba.broccoli.RegistrationForm$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(RegistrationForm.java:147)
                                                                             at com.example.zeba.broccoli.RegistrationForm$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(RegistrationForm.java:107)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
12-28 14:11:44.341 3245-3354/com.example.zeba.broccoli D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [540x960]-format:1
12-28 14:11:44.456 3245-3245/com.example.zeba.broccoli I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2f0f4385 time:209884695
12-28 14:11:44.736 3245-3245/com.example.zeba.broccoli E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.zeba.broccoli.RegistrationForm has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{6dda29d V.E..... R......D 0,0-501,174} that was originally added here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your createNewProduct to this:

```
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
   private  String fname;
   private  String lname;
   private  String email;

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegistrationForm.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating books..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        fname = fn.getText().toString();
        lname = ln.getText().toString();
        email = em.getText().toString();
    }




    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("First_Name", fname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Last_Name",lname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));


        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_book,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

In AsyncTask, onPreExecute and onPostExecute runs in main thread whereas doInBackground runs in background thread in which you are not able to perform any ui related operations.

Comment: hi chk the logcat,if need any file,just let me know

Comment: you are getting error in following line:         Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
that means you are not getting response from server side. check server side code

Comment: i have put my php file above..plz see

Answer (score 0):

You are doing UI activity in doInBackground

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String fname = fn.getText().toString();
            String lname = ln.getText().toString();
            String email = em.getText().toString();
........
}
```

getText() should be in onPreExecute or in onCreate method. Define all above string globally.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41362239/how-can-i-send-radio-button-value-and-switch-case-option-to-server-using-json-an...can u do this??

Answer (score -1):

here the corrct php for this type of code where you want add data from edittext..my mistake was that with GET and POST METHODE...

```
<?php 
include ('config.php');


$fname = $_POST['First_Name'];
$lname = $_POST['Last_Name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];



$stmt = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO UserInfo(First_Name,Last_Name,email) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$email')");



/*now only submenu items of given type will be selected*/
  if ($stmt) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }/*
else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}*/
//echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```