# how can i send radio button value and switch case option to server using json android?

Tags: android, json, switch-statement, radio-group

I'm trying to make a registration form where all values are saving on the server, but i dont know how to send the radio buttons' value and switch option buttons' value to server.
I tried implementing this for the Radio buttons, but when this activity opens, it only shows radio button value that too only once. Kindly tell me the correct way of doing this for both radio button and switch?

## Registration Activity

```
package com.example.zeba.broccoli;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RegistrationForm extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText fn,ln,mb,em,pw,cpw,dob,gen;
    Switch sw;
    RadioGroup male,feml;
    Switch swth;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;



    private static String url_create_book = "http://cloud.....com/broccoli/creatinfo.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";




    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    Context c;
    int i=0;


    Button sub;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_form);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


         fn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fnm) ;
       ln=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lnm) ;
         mb=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile) ;
         em=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email) ;
        pw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass) ;
         cpw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cpass) ;


        RadioButton male=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rgm) ;

        RadioButton feml=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rgf) ;

        Switch swth=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.mySwitch) ;

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sub2);

        addListenerOnButton();

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
                // startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationForm.this, Home.class)); 
            }
        });
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        RadioGroup rgrp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg);
        RadioButton radioButton;
        // get selected radio button from radioGroup
        int selectedId = rgrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        // find the radiobutton by returned id
        radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

        Toast.makeText(RegistrationForm.this,
                radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private  String fname;
        private  String lname;
        private  String email;

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegistrationForm.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating books..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            fname = fn.getText().toString();
            lname = ln.getText().toString();
            email = em.getText().toString();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("First_Name", fname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Last_Name",lname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_book,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

## XML File

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.zeba.broccoli.Login">




<!-- Registration Form -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="20dip"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <!-- Full Name Label -->

            <EditText android:id="@+id/fnm"

                android:hint="First Name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>

            <EditText android:id="@+id/lnm"

                android:hint="Last Name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"

                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>


            <EditText android:id="@+id/mobile"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:hint="Mobile Number"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
            <!-- Password Label -->


            <EditText android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"

                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>

            <EditText android:id="@+id/pass"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:hint="password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"

                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
            <!-- Register Button -->



            <EditText android:id="@+id/cpass"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:hint="Confirm password"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>


            <EditText android:id="@+id/dob"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:hint="Date of Birth(Optional)"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
            <!-- Register Button -->


            <!-- Link to Login Screen -->


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gen"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:text="Gender"
                android:textSize="18dp"/>


            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                >
                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/rg"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    >
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rgm"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:checked="true"

                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:text="Male"
                        />
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rgf"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:checked="false"

                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:text="Female"
                        />
                </RadioGroup>
            </RelativeLayout>



            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#c0c0c0"/>



            <TextView android:id="@+id/rupdates"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:text="Receive updates on offers, promotions and discounts"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView android:id="@+id/sms"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                    android:text="Subscribe to sms"

                    android:textSize="20dip"
                    />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/sub2"
                    style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:text="Submit"
                    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"

                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:elevation="0dp" />


            </RelativeLayout>






        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Registration Form Ends -->
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value of checked radio button from `OnCheckedChangedListener`

```
rgrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
            RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: i tried to put ur code but it gives me error..can u tell me where i shud put it

Comment: `public void addListenerOnButton() {


        RadioGroup rgrp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg);


//HERE

    }`

Answer (score 0):

try this out incase of radio button it works for me.

```
radio_button_value1 = ((RadioButton) findViewById(radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```

above code is to get value of the radio button.

replace your this code

```
// get selected radio button from radioGroup
        int selectedId = rgrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

with this code and test

```
// get selected radio button from radioGroup
 int selectedId = rgrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId().getText().toString();
```

hope this updated code helps you.you just have to replace and check

Comment: i tries but it gives me red line on getTexttoString..cannot resolve method

Comment: actuallt when i tried my code at the start in toast the value comes from radio button but i want on button click and tht too when i click any option and not the default one

Comment: so as i can understand you have a radio group with 2 radio buttons one for male and other female. and you want the value when user clicks on either male radio button or female radio button .Am i right ?

Comment: have you got a solution ?

Comment: yes...what i did was rite just need to put that code inside sub button

Answer (score 0):

Add a global String variable gender and boolean variable switchValue.

```
String gender="Male" ;
boolean switchValue = false ;
```

Inside RadioGroupListener Method

```
 public void addListenerOnButton() {
    RadioGroup rgrp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg);
    rgrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            if(i==R.id.rgm){
              gender="Male" ; 
             }else{
              gender="Female";
         }
    }
    });
    Toast.makeText(RegistrationForm.this,
            radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

For Getting the switch state

```
switchValue = swth.isChecked();
```

Comment: can u tell me in my coding where shud i post for switch??

Comment: Inside on preexceute method

Comment: it gives me error..can u post ur code in my class ..n post tht here..coz when i tried urs its nt working

Answer (score -1):

i gt my answer by myself just need to use that code inside button:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

            RadioGroup rgrp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg);

            RadioButton radioButton;

            int selectedId = rgrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            Toast.makeText(RegistrationForm.this,
                    radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```